# azure internal load balancer how does return packet route back

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I did some testing on this. And confused about how the internal network flow work.

From Requester -> LB -> Backend looks like there is no SNAT as the limitation mentioned. Do TCP Dump on the backend... The src IP is Requester

How does the packet come back? Looks like Backend -> Requester directly

However, the requester will see the packet comes from the LB IP, which means there must be some SNAT happening in the middle to translate Requester IP to LB IP before arriving at the requester?

This is really a weird setup....  Who is doing returning packet SNAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer from comment section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-internal-overview. Asked same question there and got answer below which makes sense

It's only weird if you assume Load Balancer is a proxy :-)..

Load Balancer is part of the SDN stack.  It maps flows (rather than terminating them), and in turn provides very high scale and performance.  We rewrite the destination from the Load Balancer frontend (VIP) to the destination address and destination port in your deployment.  On the return path, we rewrite the source address to the frontend of Load Balancer (VIP) and the source port becomes that of the frontend.  The SDN stack is doing these translations on the way in and out.

Let's also be specific about the term SNAT.  Inbound there is destination address translation and on the way out there is source address translation.  However, if SNAT means port masquerading source address translation, this is only in play for outbound originated flows from the VM.

Does that make more sense now?